# implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' failed

Tags: android, android-studio

So, I have a problem while running the Android Project. It is said 
that

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

I found a file in .\idea\libraries >>>>> com_android_support_support_media_compat_26_1_0

I have tried to remove or rename the file of com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 to 27.1.1, but it failed.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sbyparking.car.surabayaparking"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Do you guys have any ideas what should I do? Since I am new to Android Studio.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm facing the same problem so i did for temporary    `//noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1st Solution :

- check Offline mode is on or off if this on then please off.
- Now go on Tools>SDK Manager>Open one Dialog box in this Dialog Select **SDK Platform** And Check **Android 7.1.1(Nougat)** and Download.

Now Go on : **File & Select Sync Project with Gradle Files**

Above Solution work for you.

---

### 2nd Solution :

If you want to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` then follow bellow steps:

**Change :**

`compileSdkVersion 27` TO `compileSdkVersion 26`

`minSdkVersion 21` TO `minSdkVersion 15`

`targetSdkVersion 27` TO `targetSdkVersion 26`

**Finally Change :**

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

**TO**

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

Now Go on : **File & Select Sync Project with Gradle Files**

- **`Clean & Rebuild Project`**

---